# hMail Server - Connection failed

Tags: email, smtp, hmail-server

I am having trouble with my hMail server. I am getting logs of errors in the logs saying

> "SMTPC"   1840    0   "2017-12-22 09:58:01.745"   "TCP"   "SMTPDeliverer -
>   Message 1170761 - Connection failed: Host name: 203.147.156.193,
>   message: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did
>   not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection
>   failed because connected host has failed to respond"

This has all started since we got blacklisted, we an incident that caused our ip to end up on some blacklists, since then I have added a rule on our Mikrotik router to route all port 25 from our mail server though a different external IP. This has resolve all the spam bounce backs but i am now getting a lot of connection failed bounce backs.

I am at loss as to where to go from here.

**hMail Diagnostics**

> Test: Collect server details hMailServer version: hMailServer
>   5.4.1-B1951 Database type: MSSQL
>
> Test: Test IPv6 IPv6 support is available in operating system.
>
> Test: Test outbound port SMTP relayer not in use. Attempting
>   mail.hmailserver.com:25... Trying to connect to host
>   mail.hmailserver.com... Trying to connect to TCP/IP address
>   5.189.183.138 on port 25. Received: 220 mail.hmailserver.com ESMTP. Connected successfully.
>
> Test: Test backup directory ERROR: Backup directory has not been
>   specified.
>
> Test: Test MX records Trying to resolve MX records for
>   attachments.companionsoftware.com.au... Host name found:
>   qit-web.qit.local
>
> Test: Test local connect Connecting to TCP/IP address in MX records
>   for local domain domain attachments.companionsoftware.com.au... Trying
>   to connect to host qit-web.qit.local... Trying to connect to TCP/IP
>   address fe80::e9e2:c285:fb4d:ef7a%14 on port 25. Trying to connect to
>   TCP/IP address fe80::b0f3:daf:daf6:9e0f%12 on port 25. Trying to
>   connect to TCP/IP address 10.243.1.16 on port 25. Received: 220
>   attachments.companionsoftware.com.au ESMTP. Connected successfully.
>
> Test: Test message file locations Relative message paths are stored in
>   the database for all messages.
>
> Test: Test IP range configuration No problems were found in the IP
>   range configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I worked this out,

In my router i had specified all traffic from [internalip:25] goes out on [externalip:25]. When i removed the specific port and routed all traffic it started working.